# Display more than one image from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have to display at my website 3 images with figcaption uploaded to mysql database (id_user(int), image(longblob),text(text) i made 3 figure each for 1 picture but i don't know how to display more than 1 image:

```
 $sql = "SELECT image, text FROM images WHERE id_user=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db_con);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
     alerts('SERVER_ERROR');
    }
     else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i", $_SESSION['id']);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result= mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);


 $result=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
    $text1 = $row['text']; // doesn't work

 }
```

It's work for one image without figcaption(text) but for same id_user i have 2 more, and i want to display it like:

```
<figure> image1 </figure> <figcaption> <?php if(!empty($text1)) { echo $text1;} ?></figcaption>
<figure> image2 </figure> fig text2
<figure> image3 </figure> fig text3
```

How to change it?
PS. I know i shoudn't upload img to database but it's just 3 images. Help me to fix it.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Embedding images as base64 inline data in your HTML is not very efficient. These need to be sent to the client every single time and cannot be cached. It's much better to send a URL to a resource that can be cached, or pushed to a CDN if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>';
 echo '<p>'.$row['description'].'</p>';
}
```

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_fetch_all() to fetch multiple rows

```
$result=mysqli_fetch_all($result);
foreach($result as $row){
  echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>';
}
```

Comment: OK but how now to get image1 image2 and image3 ? u echo everything

Comment: I 'm missing some info. Am I right that there's a row in the database for every image? In that case you can fetch all rows with mysqli_fetch_all(). The foreach loop will show all rows (and it's pictures). Or are there more fields then listed above (image1, image2, ...)?

Comment: I have columns like: id/ user_id/ image / text  So i actually have 3 images for 1 user like:  1/10/img1/description1         2/10/img2/description2    3/10/img3/description3 And i want to display it in 3 different figures, but im doing WHERE user_id=10